# Change from 192.168.x.x to 172.22.x.x

Tags: adapter

I have a sensor that has an ip address of 172.22.5.150

I want to change its ip address to 192.168.1.150.
However the only way to change it is to log into it through Ethernet.
But I cant access 172.22.5.150 on my network

My PC, router etc is on the usual 192.168.x.x. 
Is there a way I can temporarily change my network so that I can speak to the sensor?

So far what I have done is: 
Control Panel > Network Connections > RMC on adapter > Properties >
TCP/IPv4 > Properties:

```
Use the following ip address: 172.22.5.120 
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0 
Default gateway: 172.22.0.1 
Preferred DNS: 208.67.222.222 (this is for openDNS I think)
```

Do I also need to change my router?

I have an ADSL router, but I also have a netgear ethernet switch if this is of any use.

Update:

I am on Windows 7, 64-bit

Comment: You could always directly connect to the sensor over Ethernet with that static IP and not have to change anything.

Comment: You need to know the subnet mask used on the sensor and configure the same subnet mask on your computer for the 172.x.x.x ip address. You do not need a DG or DNS servers configured.

Comment: @Nathan. what do you mean by directly connect - do you mean PC to sensor with a cross-over cable?

Answer (score 3):

As long as your PC and the Sensor on the same Layer 2 network (plugged into the same switch and vlan), you should just be able to add a secondary IP to your PC's interface like the one you displayed. The router only needs to be involved if the sensor and PC are not plugged into the same layer 2 segment.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily add a secondary IP address to a host on the same Ethernet segment as the sensor. I would recommend using a prefix as long as possible for this secondary IP. You should not add any gateway or DNS servers for the secondary IP.

In order to reach `172.22.5.150` a usable configuration for the secondary IP could be `172.22.5.149/30`.

How to configure this depends on operating system. You did not specify which operating systems you have available, so I cannot provide additional details.

Comment: Thanks, but what does this mean: `172.22.5.149/30.` I'm on windows 7. What do you mean by `prefix as long as possible`

Comment: @spiderplant0 By as long as possible, I mean that there must be IP addresses for client, server, network address, and broadcast address. That means you cannot make it any longer than 30 bits. But if the address of the device would be conflicting with network address or broadcast address, you may have to make the prefix shorter. I cannot tell you how to configure it on windows 7, because I know nothing about windows 7.